# Field of view de câmaras de vigilância em Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Boa tarde Comunidade,

Tenho uma dúvida sobre Excel, em que não sei se é possível realizar tal pedido.
O meu objectivo é pegar numa planta e através de um solver, colocar câmaras de vigilância em determinados pontos da planta de modo a monitorizar toda a área (Problema de Cobertura).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta imagem representa uma dessas áreas a monitorizar. As células que têm o valor 1, representam a colocação de câmaras. Essa colocação é efectuada automaticamente com o solver, mediante algumas restrições matemáticas.

O que eu tenho andado a tentar e que não consigo, é fazer com que o FOV (field of view) de cada câmara seja representado pelo valor 1 nas quadrículas adjacentes.

Exemplo do que pretendo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver, as quadrículas adjacentes a cada câmara estão preenchidas com o FOV da câmara correspondente, mas fui eu que coloquei à mão.
Gostava de saber se existe um método de elaborar o meu pedido automaticamente, através de Visual Basic ou fórmulas, ou de outro método que não seja do meu conhecimento.

Este é meu trabalho de mestrado no tema optimização de recursos.

Qualquer informação que necessitem para me ajudarem, estarei disponível.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, 
Você pode usar a formula `SE`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz sua tabela e notei que cada câmera tem um range, mas os ranges se cruzam, então eu inseri nas células que os ranges se cruzam a seguinte formula:

```
=SE($D$6 = 1;1;SE($D$3 = 1;1;0))
```

No meu caso as células D6 e D3 são as câmeras da esquerda sendo que elas ocupam esse range:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Da mesma forma do outro lado.

Os ranges que não se cruzam (periféricos):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu coloquei a formula:

```
=SE($D$3 = 1;1;0)
```

Basta agora você adaptar a sua situação.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. O problema é que eu nunca sei qual é a câmara que está a ocupar os vértices, e cada câmara tem ranges diferentes. Por exemplo a câmara 1 ocupa 6 quadrículas enquanto a câmara 2 já ocupa 10 quadrículas. Será possível eu contactá-lo de alguma maneira e enviar-lhe um pequeno exemplo em excel? Acho que com um exemplo mais prático se consegue entender melhor o problema. No entretanto, estou a utilizar o seu método e a tentar aplica-lo.